# Illustrator: stop gradient from applying to new objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, gradient, swatches

I used a linear gradient onto a line and now it applies to every new object I create. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3):

If you would like new objects to all start with the same standard appearance, rather than the last used appearance, click the **Appearance Panel Menu** and ensure `New Art Has Basic Appearance` is **checked**.

[image]

Then, anything newly created will have a basic standard appearance. You can always go back and *uncheck* that option if you should ever *want* new art to retain the last appearance again.

Answer (score 0):

You must have that gradient assigned as default, which is why it gets used for every new object. Look in the Color palette (see below) and set you `Fill` (red arrow) and `Stroke` (green arrow) to `None` (blue arrow).

[image: illustrator color palette]